# transport a player with arrow (minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

how to make an arrow, by using teleport to the player that is closest to this

```
execute if entity @p[x=-146,y=4,z=73,dx=1.5,dy=1.5,dz=1.5,distance=..1.5] run tp @p -145.80 4.43 69.00
```

instead of the coordinates use the arrow

I need to activate this code when the arrow touches or falls around the player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you try to do, but this `execute at @e[type=minecraft:arrow] run tp @p ~ ~ ~` inside of a repeating command block seems to be similar to what you want.

Comment: I think it is at least fun to use